# MySQL order by IN order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have simple query:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE id IN (5, 2, 8, 1, 10)
```

Question is, how can i select my data and order it like in my IN.

Order must be 5, 2, 8, 1, 10.

Problem is that i have no key for order. IN data is from other query (1), but i need to safe order.

Any solutions?

(1)

```
SELECT login 
FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN users ON posts.post_id=users.id 
WHERE posts.post_n IN (
    2280219,2372244, 2345146, 2374106, 2375952, 2375320, 2371611, 2360673, 2339976, 2331440, 2279494, 2329266, 2271919, 1672114, 2301856
)
```

**Thanx for helping, solutions works but very slow, maybe find something better later, thanx anyway**

Comment: doesn't it come naturally in that order?

Comment: @Sebas no - if there's no `order by` set then there's no default ordering

Comment: but that's what he wants, as far as I understood

Comment: @swamprrunner7, could you show the other query please? Is it a separate one or does it come combined in your code?

Comment: it`s like this SELECT login FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON(posts.post_id=users.id) WHERE posts.post_n IN (2280219, 2372244, 2345146, 2374106, 2375952, 2375320, 2371611, 2360673, 2339976, 2331440, 2279494, 2329266, 2271919, 1672114, 2301856)

Comment: are you sure the join is correct? post.post_id to user.id?

Comment: i do this query for best speed results. in one query i generate ids in this query i take it very quick, but ordering -_- Yes, ids correct, its from code.

Comment: in results order is
2375952, 2375320, 2374106, 2372244, 2371611, 2360673, 2345146…

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to order by an arbitrary list would be to `ORDER BY` comparisons to each item in that list.  It's ugly, but it will work.  You may be better off sorting in whatever code you are doing the selection.

```
SELECT data FROM t1 WHERE id IN (5, 2, 8, 1, 10)
ORDER BY id = 10, id = 1, id = 8, id = 2, id = 5
```

The order is reversed because otherwise you would have to add `DESC` to each condition.

Comment: I think you can't really do that in his case, apparently the values of the IN subquery are not hardcoded in his prod. environnement

Comment: @Sebas he could always create the `ORDER BY` programatically as well

Comment: i see, but what if there are 1000 results? Wouldn't it be a bit overkill?

Comment: @Sebas probably, but I don't think there's any other way unfortunately

Comment: It`s works great, but now using SLOW filesort, it`s bad. Anyway, thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT data 
FROM table WHERE id IN (5, 2, 8, 1, 10)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 5 THEN 1 WHEN id = 2 THEN 2 WHEN id = 8 THEN 3 WHEN id = 1 THEN 4 WHEN id = 10 THEN 5 END
```

Comment: @PreetSangha you consider this more compact than my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT data FROM table
  WHERE id IN (5, 2, 8, 1, 10)
  ORDER BY FIELD (id, 5, 2, 8, 1, 10)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Might be easier to auto-generate (because it basically just needs inserting the wanted IDs comma-separated in the same order a second time) than the other solutions suggested using CASE or a number of ID=x, ID=y ...

Comment: very nice, but filesort too, maybe i never do this without filesort. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40b299/6

I think that's what you're looking for :D Adapt it to your own situation.

Answer (score 0):

To do this dynamically, and within MySql, I would suggest to do the following:

1. Create a temp table or table variable (not sure if MySql has these), with two columns:

> ```
> OrderID mediumint not null auto_increment
> InValue mediumint -(or whatever type it is)
> ```

1. Insert the values of the IN clause in order, which will generate ID's in order of insertion
2. Add a `JOIN` to your query on this temp table
3. Change your Order By to be

> ```
> order by TempTable.OrderID
> ```

1. Drop temp table (again, in SQL inside a stored proc, this is automatic, not sure about MySql so mentioning here for full disclosure)

This effectively circumvents the issue of you not having a key to order by in your table ... you create one. Should work.

Comment: His main concern is speed, this won't help that

Comment: Yes, speed is everything, thanx for help.

Comment: This is the most dynamic way, I think, but definitely not the fastest way, especially in MySql which I just read does not support Table Variables (sucks!)

Comment: Would using memory storage engine for the temp table make it fast enough? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html.